# Problem in HQL when try to get count of a property (that is entity) and its value

Tags: nhibernate, group-by, entity, hql

In my project, I have two entity, first PaperEntity contains several properties (consisting of value types and also reference types -reference to other entities-) and second is PaperStatusEntity.
PaperEntity has a property named Result of type PaperStatusEntity (and also a property named locked of type bool)

Imagine you have near 500 papers and just 8 paper status defined in database.
I want to find how much every status is used? for example status1 used 58 times and status2 used 130 times and so on.
I write below HQL

```
select paper.Result, Count(paper.Result) from PaperEntity paper group by paper.Result
```

this hql generates below error:

```
Column 'Conference_PaperStatusesTable.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

generated sql is:

```
select paperentit0_.Result as col_0_0_, count(paperentit0_.Result) as col_1_0_, paperstatu1_.Id as Id48_, paperstatu1_.Version as Version48_, paperstatu1_.CreationTime as Creation3_48_, paperstatu1_.Portal as Portal48_, paperstatu1_.TitleCodeName as TitleCod5_48_, paperstatu1_.Enabled as Enabled48_, paperstatu1_.RefereeChoice as RefereeC7_48_, paperstatu1_.OrderIndex as OrderIndex48_, paperstatu1_.ContactMessageTemplate as ContactM9_48_ from Conference_PapersTable paperentit0_ inner join Conference_PaperStatusesTable paperstatu1_ on paperentit0_.Result=paperstatu1_.Id, Conference_PaperStatusesTable paperstatu2_ where paperentit0_.Result=paperstatu2_.Id group by paperentit0_.Result
```

If I try to group data with a value type property like 'Locked' (that is bool), no problems and all things are ok

also If I use Criteria instead of HQL, works truly:

```
IList result = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(PaperEntity))
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.RowCount()).Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Result"))).List();

foreach (var item in result) {
        object[] value = item as object[];
        yield return new Pair<PaperStatusEntity, int>(value[1] as PaperStatusEntity, (int)value[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a simple data type for the database engine to group by.  If paper.Result is another entity you'll probably need to join to the PaperStatusEntity table.

Something like:

```
select paper.Result, Count(paper.Result) 
from PaperEntity as paper 
join paper.Result as status
group by status.Id
```

If PaperStatus is mapped as a component you can also access Result.Id directly.

Comment: PaperStatusEntity mapped as different entity

Comment: I executed query to decided, but exception 'Path expected for join!' was thrown

Comment: I defined the join wrong.  You need to join to paper.Result instead of direct to PaperEntityStatus (this is why it didn't know what join path to take).  s/b fixed now.

Comment: I tried to join, but I don't know I written join truly. could you write a sample?

Comment: What error do you get when running the query as currently defined? (select paper.Result, Count(paper.Result) 
from PaperEntity as paper 
join paper.Result as status
group by status.Id)

Comment: error is "Column 'Conference_PapersTable.Result' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. " join does not make error, but main problem remaines

Answer (score 0):

HQL `group by` is not smart enough to project all the properties of an entity when grouping by it. You have to either:

- Specify all the properties
- Select just those you need (id, description, whatever)
- Use a subquery to get the count

The reason why it's working with Criteria is that it selects **just the id** when you use `Projections.GroupProperty`, creating uninitialized proxies.

This can create a **SELECT N+1** problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT paper.Result, Count(paper.Result) 
FROM PaperEntity paper
JOIN paper.Result as status
GROUP BY paper.Result
```

Note that you would rather use a "FROM PaperStatusEntity" and join the papers
Because with the actual thing you are trying to do, you may not get a count for a PaperStatusEntity if no paper use this status (this means you don't get a count=0, you just get no count)

You can also use the @Formula annotation so that, for a given status, you can do paperStatusEntity.getPaperNumber()

Just add something like

```
@Formula("select count() from PaperEntity paper where paper.result_id = id");
public int getPaperNumber();
```

(should be adapted)

(I use Hibernate but it should be the same?)